# node.js http request using SAML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, saml-2.0

i am facing an architectural problem with node.js using express for saml authentication against ms adfs. my problem is, that i have to call a webservice from within my node.js application that expects saml authentication (using the same idp as express). i have no idea how to realize this scenario.

would be great to get some hints on how to solve this problem. is there any chance to extract the saml assertion from the express library and pass it to the webservice i am calling ?

thanks!